# Codeigniter Image Resize() is not working on greater than 1000px width of Image

Tags: image, codeigniter, resize

Below is the code when i try with the image less than 1000px width its working fine but when i tried with greater than 1000px its not working.

```
$img_array = array();
    $img_array['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $img_array['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $img_array['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $thumb_name = $img_array['new_image'] = './public/image/thumb/' . $file;
    //you need this setting to tell the image lib which image to process
    $img_array['source_image'] = $path;
    $img_array['width'] = 180;
    $img_array['height'] = 250;


    $this->image_lib->clear(); // added this line
    $this->image_lib->initialize($img_array); // added this line
    if (!$this->image_lib->resize())
    {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors(); exit;
    }
    return $thumb_name;
    }
```

Comment: try the code and let me know its working for you or not?

Comment: file upload is working fine but resize give error "The path to the image is not correct. Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image."

Comment: check your server gd library is enable or not\

Comment: see the description here to on the on the libary http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

Create a model name as Image_model in Models Folder put this code in your model

```
class Image_model extends CI_Model {
public function __construct()   {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
}
public function do_resize($filename)
{

    $source_path =  'uploads/' . $filename;
    //create a directory thumb in uploads set as target path
   $target_path =  'uploads/thumb/thumb_'.$filename;

    $config_manip = array(

        'image_library' => 'gd2',
        'source_image' => $source_path,
        'new_image' => $target_path,
        'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
        'width' => 180,
        'height' => 250
    );
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config_manip);
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config_manip);


    if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        die();
    }
    // clear //
    //$this->image_lib->clear();
}

public function img_upload()
{
    $config = array(
        'upload_path' => "uploads",
        'allowed_types' => "*",
        'overwrite' => TRUE,
        'max_size' => "5048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
        'max_height' => "3000",
        'max_width' => "3000"
    );
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if($this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $response   =    array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        //here calling the function do_resize
       $this->do_resize($response['upload_data']['file_name']);
        //return $response;
    }
    /*else{
        $error              =   array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
        //print_r($error);die(); 

    }*/
  }
}
```

and call the function controller like this here is the controller

```
class your_controller extends CI_Controller {

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('image_model');
}
   // here the function to save name in database
public function add() {
        $data                       =   array();
        $config                     =   array();    
        if(isset($_FILES)){
             $config                =   $this->image_model->img_upload();
             $file_data             =   $this->upload->data();
             $data['image']         =   $file_data['file_name'];
        }
          else
            $data['image']          =   "no-image";
        // here the function in your model to save the name of image in your database                    
         $last_id               =       $this->your_model->save($data);
         $this->load->view('your_view');
    }
```

Comment: file upload is working fine but resize give error                           "The path to the image is not correct.  Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image."